# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django REST APIView POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to write a POST request for a game API and am passing some data from the GET request and some through this POST request. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError 'gameround'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user_id = 1
        else:
            current_user_id = request.user.pk
        gameround = request.GET['gameround']
        random_resource = request.GET['resource']
        created = datetime.now()
        score = 0
        origin = ''
        name = request.POST['name']
        language = request.POST['language']

        user_input_tag = Tag.objects.create(name=name, language=language)
        tag_serializer = TagSerializer(user_input_tag)

        if Tagging.objects.all().filter(tag=user_input_tag).exists():
            # if tagging like this exists, save tagging anyway and leave tag unchanged
            score += 5
            user_input_tagging = Tagging.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                        gameround=gameround,
                                                        resource=random_resource,
                                                        tag=user_input_tag,
                                                        created=created,
                                                        score=score,
                                                        origin=origin)

            tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(user_input_tagging)

            return Response({'tag and ': tag_serializer.data}, {'tagging': tagging_serializer.data})

        elif not Tagging.objects.all().filter(tag=user_input_tag).exists():
            # save tagging otherwise and del tag?
            user_input_tagging = Tagging.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                        gameround=gameround,
                                                        resource=random_resource,
                                                        tag=user_input_tag,
                                                        created=created,
                                                        score=score,
                                                        origin=origin)
            user_input_tagging.save()
            tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(user_input_tagging)
            return Response({'tagging only': tagging_serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have key `gameround` in your `GET`. You can get gameround data as

```
gameround = request.GET.get('gameround')
```

If default value is not given then it defaults to `None`.

Or you can set `default` value as

```
gameround = request.GET.get('gameround', '')
```

Comment: This seems to work. Does the same count for POST then? such as '''name = request.POST.get('name')'''? I have added this and it doesn't throw any errors anymore but only {"name":["This field is required."],"language":["This field is required."]}.

Comment: Yes it will work in `POST` too. It is better to use because it will not throw `MultiValueDictKeyError` since it will set `default` value. Otherwise you have to check manually if `key` exists or not.

Comment: It is because the value of `name` and `language` obtained here is null and in your `models.py` you have set both fields as not null that is why you are getting this error while creating new `Tag`